# jQuery function .prepend() don't work with wordpress nav menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu

I have a menu in Wordpress and I want to hook up Appointlet script to it. The code is here:

```js
(function(e,t,n,r)
{
    if(e)return;
    t._appt=true;
    var i=n.createElement(r),s=n.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];
   i.async=true;i.src='//dje0x8zlxc38k.cloudfront.net/loaders/s-min.js';      
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(i,s)
})

(window._appt,window,document,"script")
```

```html
<div data-appointlet="tfracine">
</div>
```

My idea is to create menu item with blank name, get its id (for example, "#menu-item-66"). Then add my code in front of it using jQuery function.prepend().
So I created custom js file, included it in the header.php file and the code inside the file was this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#menu-item-66" ).prepend( "Test" ); 
});
```

I started with the word "Test" to figure out if it works.

Unfortunately, nothing happened and I have lack of skills to figure out why. Any suggestions or smarter way to do it?

Comment: You need to do somethning like: $('#menu-item-66').prepend('<div data-appointlet="tfracine">
</div>');

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `.prepend()` function will prepend a jQuery element, not a string.

So, you have to create a jQuery element by doing:

`var newElement = $('<p>New Element</p>');`

In your case, what you could do is:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu-item-66').prepend($('<p>This is a jQuery element</p>'); 
});`

For a complete reference, check the [.prepend() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) out.

Answer (score 0):

.prepend() and .prependTo() adds the specified content as the first child. 
The question is bit not clear. Do you want to insert your script inside your 
div ?